# Only top left corner is rounded instead of topLeft and bottomLeft

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to make UIView topLeft and bottomLeft corners rounded however for some reason only topLeft has border radius. What can cause this?

This is What I am doing:

I have Extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

And I apply it to view like this:

```
myView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 10.0)
```

I am using it inside cell and I am also using auto-layout.

At the moment it looks like this(green is the view I am talking about) but I want the bottomLeft to have corner radius also:

[image]

Comment: I experienced a similar issue a few weeks ago. I was able to resolve it by increasing the width / height of the view. Not sure why though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your timing. Your extension relies on `self.bounds`. But if you call this extension too early, such as `viewDidLoad`, those `bounds` have not yet been determined. Your view is sized by auto layout; that means you don't have bounds until your view's `layoutSubviews` or your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called.